How does a Banach space $X$ become a Hilbert space?
The Banach space and Hilbert space can be replaced by normed space and inner product space, respectively. For simplicity, the space is over $\mathbb{R}$.
As we know, a norm $\| \cdot \|$ can be induced by a inner product if and only if the norm satisfies parallelogram equation $\|x+y\|^2 + \|x-y\|^2 = 2(\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2)$. However, if a norm doesn't satisfy that identity, we can modify this norm $\|\cdot\|$ to be a equivalent norm $\|\cdot\|'$ and $\|\cdot\|'$ can be induced by a inner product.
For instance, the norm $\|(x,y)\| = |x| + |y|$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ doesn't fit parallelogram equation, but $\|(x,y)\|'=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ can be induced by inner product. Obviously, $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|'$ are equivalent.
How can we to determine which normed space can become a inner product space? Are there some topological condition to judge a Hilbert space?
-Equivalent norms' meaning is that, the new norm maintains topology. Namely there are two numbers $c_1, c_2$ such that $c_1 \|\cdot\| \leq \|\cdot\|' \leq c_2\|\cdot\|$.
-Because every Hilbert space is reflexive, we also require the Banach space here to have the same properties.
-In Properties of a reflexive Banach space isomorphic to a Hilbert space, some people said “One such result is that a Banach space is isomorphic to a Hilbert space if and only if every closed subspace is topologically complemented. ” But I don't know its reason.

PlanetMath labels this as the Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri theorem. Wikipedia's article on complemented subspaces includes some relevant references.

Joram Lindenstrauss and Lior Tzafriri. On the complemented subspaces
problem. Israel Journal of Mathematics, 9(2):263–269, 1971.

What you say is not correct. "However, if a norm doesn't satisfy that identity, we can modify this norm ∥⋅∥ to be a equivalent norm ∥⋅∥′ and ∥⋅∥′ can be induced by a inner product." This is true in finite dimension. Not in general.

@GiuseppeNegro Yes, you're right. It should add "in some specific cases". This is just a motive for my question.

Since gerw mentioned the characterization via type and cotype (Theorem 7.3.1 in [2]), I thought I should mention a characterization via the related notion of Fourier type.
A Banach space $X$ has Fourier type $p\in [1,2]$ if the classic Fourier transform from $L^p(\mathbb R) \to L^{p'}(\mathbb R)$ extends to a bounded operator from the Bochner spaces $L^p(\mathbb R;X) \to L^{p'}(\mathbb R;X)$. The Plancherel theorem (Theorem 2.4.7 in [1]) implies that Hilbert spaces have Fourier type $p=2$ whereas a theorem due to  Kwapień (Theorem 2.1.18 in  [1]) implies that if $X$ has fourier type $p=2$ then $X$ is (isomorphic to) a Hilbert space.
Fourier type is related to type and cotype:
$$ \text{ Fourier type } p \implies \text{ type $p$ and cotype $p'$}$$
but the converse is not true. A partial converse is that nontrivial type $p \in (1,2]$ implies nontrivial Fourier type $\tilde p \in (1,2]$ (in general $p \neq \tilde p$)
Of course there is a plethora of characterization of Hilbert spaces (up to isomorphism). Here are a few more examples that characterize Hilbert spaces (up to isomorphism). Suppose $X$ is a Banach space.

(Theorem 4.6.12 in [1], also Theorem 2.1 in [5] for a proof) $X$ is a Hilbert space iff there exists a bi-convex function $\zeta \colon X\times X \to \mathbb R$ with $\zeta(0,0)=1$ and
$$\zeta(x,y) \le \|x+y\|,\quad \forall x,y \in S_X .$$
In fact, the norm of  Banach space satisfying the above also satisfies the parallelogram law so $X$ is a Hilbert space. (The other direction is obvious by taking $\zeta(x,y) = 1 + (x\mid y)$)

(Corollary 8.6.2 in [2]) $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space iff every bounded family of operators $\mathcal T \subset \mathcal L(X)$ is $R$-bounded (Definition 5.3.13 in [1]).

[Corollary 9.2.12 in [2]) $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space iff the space of radonifying operators [Definition 9.1. in [2]) $\gamma(L^2(S),X) \simeq L^2(S;X)$ where $S$ is a measure space such that $\dim (L^2(S))=\infty$.

(Theorem 14.7.9 in [3]) $X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space iff the Besov space $H^{s,p}(\mathbb R^d;X) $ is isomorphim to the Triebel–Lizorkin space $F_{p,2}^s(\mathbb R^d;X)$. For integers $s=m$ these are isomorphic to the Sobolev space $W^{m,p}(\mathbb R^d;X)$.

If $X$ is smooth then $X$ is a Hilbert space (not only up to isomorphism) if and only if the duality mapping $J \colon X \to X^*$ is linear. Best reference I could find is Proposition 3.7 in [4] but the authors do not include a proof.

If $X$ is reflexive and strictly convex then $X$ is a Hilbert space if and only if every metric projection $P \colon X \to V$ on each closed subspace is linear. This is essentially due to the  Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri theorem (see this post.)

$X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space if and only if $X$ is 2-smooth and 2-convex (see this answer).

$X$ is isomorphic to a Hilbert space if and only if $X$ has martingale type $2$ and martingale cotype $2$.


[1] Analysis in Banach spaces volume I
[2] Analysis in Banach spaces volume II
[3] Analysis in Banach spaces volume III
[4] Charles Chidume. Duality maps in Banach spaces. Geometric properties of Banach spaces and nonlinear iterations, pages 19–28, 2009
[5] Burkholder, D. L. Martingale transforms and the geometry of Banach spaces.
In Probability in Banach spaces, III (Medford, Mass., 1980), volume 860
of Lecture Notes in Math., pages 35–50. Springer, Berlin-New York, 1981b.
367, 368

This is a nice collection of criteria! However, I am wondering if they characterize Hilbert spaces or Banach spaces which are isomorphic to a Hilbert space. At least 5 and 6 should characterize Hilbert spaces, if I am not mistaken.

I had a brief look into your reference [1]. In item 1, you should refer to Theorem 4.6.12. This is also a property, which characterizes Hilbert spaces. (Btw: in [1], the authors speak of "a Banach space $X$ is isometric to a Hilbert space..." For me, this sounds a little bit strange, since if $X$ is isometric to a Hilbert space, it is actually a Hilbert space....?)

@gerw I have updated my answer. Indeed, it sounds strange... I could look at the actual proof later

@gerw The original proof in Burkholder's paper shows that if a space satisfies 1. then its norm satisfies the parallelogram law so $X$ is indeed a Hilbert space. Not sure why the authors of [1] refer to this as "isometric to a Hilbert space"

One can show that a Banach space is isomorphic to a Hilbert space if and only if it is of type $2$ and cotype $2$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_and_cotype_of_a_Banach_space. I think that this is closest to the "Hilbert if and only if parallelogram identity".
